# Question about induced current with an axis parallel to magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

I am currently going over a physics test. One of the questions asked if a square loop of wire perpendicular to a uniform magnetic field entering the page has an induced charge if it is spun counterclockwise on an axis that is parallel to the uniform magnetic field. I answered no because there is no change in flux because the perpendicular area does not change therefore there is no induced emf. However, the online system told me that this was wrong. I am wondering if anyone can explain to me why this is true.

Thank you

Comment: Electron in the square loop gets a velocity v=wr ,due to which an electronic current induced ,so magnetic force and loretnz force will act f=evb ,and induced emf will be 1/2Bwl^2